# Oracle Service Bus Transport for Apache Kafka : Throwing WLSTException while running install.py

Tags: apache-kafka, osb

I'm Tring to configure KAFKA in OSB 12c.
I followed the exact steps shown in this blog
https://github.com/oracle/osb-kafka-transport
But while trying to run **java weblogic.WLST install.py** it's throwing **WLSTException**.
Even I tried this after running the OSB server and KAFKA server but still showed the same.

```
    ***** Service Bus Kafka Transport Install *****
    
    No stack trace available.
    Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
      File "C:\osb-kafka-transport-sample-master\install\install.py", line 13, in ?
      File "<iostream>", line 19, in connect
      File "<iostream>", line 553, in raiseWLSTException
    WLSTException: Error occurred while performing connect : "No valid username/password or userConfigFile/userKeyFile provided"
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit `install.py` to give connection string to Admin server and then re-execute it:

```
connect('username','Password','t3://host:port')
```